# Problem with making lowercase special characters with an accent

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a String that is a phrase, in that sentence everything is in capital letters, what I need is that everything is in small letters, when I use .toLower () everything works fine except for the character of 'É', how can I do that in small letters without having to use a .Replace ("É", "é"), I want to avoid using the replacement in case in the future there are those types of exceptions, something more general

Comment: I try Saamer code, it works fine, so you can try it. If you still have issue, please provide a String that is a phrase here, and post some code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you. I went to [try.dot.net](http://try.dot.net) and I put in "É" and it printed "é" for this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("É".ToLower());
```

Alternatively, you could also use the `ToLower()` constructor overload and pass in the `CultureInfo` to tell .Net you are trying to use a spanish or french language, as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("É".ToLower(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES", false)));
```